# How to make ucwords work for single quotes only and not apostrophes?

Tags: php

I want to turn this text:

> She's saying it's time to 'find a solution'.

into this text:

> She's Saying It's Time To 'Find A Solution'.

I'm currently using both ucwords and this ucwords-related function to make capital letters after single quotes: (I found in the [comment section](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) of php.net.)

```
function ucwordsMore ($str) {
    $str = str_replace("' ","'",ucwords(str_replace("'","' ",$str)));
    return $str;
}
```

However, this function results in this:

> She'S Saying It'S Time To 'Find A Solution'.

How can I best keep **letters after apostrophes small**, and **letters after single quotes big**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It usually works with a bit of pattern matching:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\w[\w']*/e", "ucwords('\\0')", $str);
```

`\w` is okay for ASCII letters and numbers. For international text use `\pL` and the `/u` modifier.

Comment: +1 - In general, I like to stay away from the `/e` modifier, but this is a very elegant solution.

Comment: Mario, how would you use pL and u in this example? Because letters in front of non-English letters become big as well. Sorry for asking... I'm not a regex expert...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but there is no difference between a single quote and an apostrophe.  You are going to have to use something to differentiate the two if that makes sense. A heuristic you can use is if there are only one or two consecutive chars after the apostrophe you can assume it's a contraction and not a singly quoted string.

EDIT: This is a stupid heuristic that I don't recommend but I did it anyways.

```
function ucwordsMore ($str) {
    $str = str_replace("' ","'",ucwords(str_replace("'","' ",$str)));
    return $str;
}

$string  = "She's Saying It's Time To 'Find A Solution'.";

$string = ucwordsMore($string);
//string now equals = She'S Saying It'S Time To 'Find A Solution'.
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
    if($string[$i] == "'"){
      if($i +2 < strlen($string) && $string[$i] == "'"&& $string[$i+1] != " "&& $string[$i+2] == " "){
          $string[$i+1] = strtolower($string[$i+1]); //replace
    }
      if($i +3 < strlen($string) && $string[$i] == "'"&& $string[$i+1] != " "&& $string[$i+2] != " "&& $string[$i+3] == " "){
          $string[$i+1] = strtolower($string[$i+1]); //replace
          $string[$i+2] = strtolower($string[$i+2]); //replace
    }

}
}
echo $string;
//$string - "She's Saying It's Time To 'Find A Solution'."
```

Comment: I know that, the question is what?

Comment: I added an edit about a heuristic you can use.  If you want to be more accurate you can basically create an array of words that you don't want to be capitalized and check against that as you iterate through the list.  Basically what you are using single quotes for is what you should use double quotes for.

Comment: Should be a comment, not an answer... and an alternative and more accurate heuristic would be the presence/absence of a space before the apostrophe

Comment: the heuristic idea makes definitely sense. if one char is after the single quote, then it should be kept small. i guess this makes more sense than looping through a list. how shall I best go about it? how can I identify if there is only one char after a single quote - or if there is a space before it as Mark just mentioned?

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = ucwords($str);

$str = preg_replace_callback("/(^|\\s+)'[a-z]/", create_function(
    '$matches',
    'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'
), $str);
```